# Checking if date text has milliseconds and seconds in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to parse a date from a text format to see if milliseconds and seconds were included in it.
For e.g.

```
let text = '2016-02-02 14:30:34.234';
const timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
// const hasMS = utcParse('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.')(text);
// const hasSeconds = utcParse('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:')(text);

const hasMS = !!moment.tz(text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss.', timezone);
console.log('hasMS', hasMS);
const hasSeconds = !!moment.tz(text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:', timezone);
console.log('hasSeconds', hasSeconds);
```

Basically I am trying to replace the commented code. utcParse() from d3.time-format would check if the date text has milliseconds and seconds in it. I tried a couple of things for momentjs library, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Regular expressions you can check if certain parts of the string are present.

If you call `matchDateTime()` with the string you get an array back with all the matched groups.

```js
let text_min = '2016-02-02 14:30';
let text_sec = '2016-02-02 14:30:34';
let text_ms = '2016-02-02 14:30:34.234';

function matchDateTime(text) { return text.match(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d)(?::(\d\d)(?:\.(\d\d\d))?)?/); }

function hasSeconds(text) { return !!matchDateTime(text)[6]; }
function hasMilliSeconds(text) { return !!matchDateTime(text)[7]; }

function testTimeString(text) {
  console.log(text, "hasSeconds=", hasSeconds(text));
  console.log(text, "hasMilliSeconds=", hasMilliSeconds(text));
}

testTimeString(text_min);
testTimeString(text_sec);
testTimeString(text_ms);

console.log(matchDateTime(text_ms));
```